# Is this set bounded??

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a is finite dimensional Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators from $E$ to $E$.

For $T\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ and $M\in\mathcal{L}(E)^+$. We consider the following set 
$$W_M(T)=\{\langle MT x\; |\;x\rangle\;\;\hbox{such that}\;\;\|M^{1/2}x\|=1\;\}.$$

I want to see if $W_M(T)$ bounded or not when $E$ is a finite dimensional Hilbert space.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $M^{1/2}$?

Comment: It is the square root of $M$ and we have $M^{1/2}M^{1/2}=M$.

Comment: Why should it exist?

Comment: It exist since $M$ is positive.

Comment: @Mr.Chip A special case of the Spectral Theorem says that any positive operator is diagonalizable (with non-negative entries on the diagonal).

Comment: Then please diagonalize $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$ over $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $W_M(T)$ can be empty: take $M=0$.

If $M$ is not invertible then the set can be unbounded: Take $M=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$, $T=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$. Then for $x=\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}$ we have $\langle MTx,x\rangle = x_1x_2$. We can set $x_1=1$ then $\|M^{1/2}x\|=1$ regardless of the choice of $x_2$.

If $M$ is symmetric positive definite then $W_M(T)$ is the continuous image of a compact set, hence compact.

Comment: @Student edited